# Any licensing issues with an AGPL Docker container used for integration testing?

Tags: gpl

Consider a proprietary software service consisting of micro-services that use Amazon S3 for storage. For integration testing I would like to put together a docker-compose file that consists of individual Docker containers for our micro-services and a container for minio, an AGPL S3-compatible implementation.

This would be just for local testing, our deployed services use the real AWS S3 services.

So, would the AGPL license for minio trigger the copyleft requirements in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem like the AGPL would cause any issues in your case.

The AGPLv3 triggers conditions when you do one of the following:

- you give someone else a copy of the AGPLv3-covered software, whether in source or binary form
- you modify the AGPLv3-covered software or otherwise create a derivative work
- other people interact with the AGPLv3-covered software remotely over a network

None of these apply:

- You are only deploying the software within your organization and aren't giving copies to anyone else. Your use of cloud platforms is irrelevant in this context.
- You are not modifying the MinIO software, and are not combining parts of the MinIO software with your proprietary software. The MinIO server software is clearly distinct from your proprietary services.
- You are only using the software for internal testing, so there are no users who could interact with this software over a network.